# Safe to change ownership of /etc/hosts?

Tags: macos, vagrant, hosts-file

I use Vagrant and the plugin hostupdater to add an entry to my mac's host file. The entry is only added when Vagrant runs, it's deleted when Vagrant is stopped.

In order to get the plugin to work, I have to add a command to my sudoers file:

```
# Allow passwordless startup of Vagrant with vagrant-hostsupdater.
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_HOSTS_ADD = /bin/sh -c echo "*" >> /etc/hosts
Cmnd_Alias VAGRANT_HOSTS_REMOVE = /usr/bin/env sed -i -e /*/ d /etc/hosts
%admin ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: VAGRANT_HOSTS_ADD, VAGRANT_HOSTS_REMOVE
```

In order for the above to work, I have to change ownership of `/etc/hosts` from root to admin. Is it safe to change ownership of my hosts file?

Thanks.

Comment: The above should mean that you don't need to change permission of the /etc/hosts file.  If the user running the command is a member of the admin group, it should just work.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a good idea to change ownership of the /etc/hosts file. Have you looked into using this plugin? https://github.com/devopsgroup-io/vagrant-hostmanager

Comment: Can you elaborate why it's a not a good idea to change the ownership of the host file from root to admin?